# No heat overheating when moving

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

Hey car overheating and have no heat,it doesn't over hit when idle.but when the car start moving them temp rise quick.I check the radiator the top hose is warm and the bottom hose is cold

Comment: Doggy. Looks like your first time posting here.   Welcome. It’s not clear at all what’s going on with your car.  Year/ Make/ Model, odometer mileage and your location would be very helpful.  Possible clogged radiator, low coolant, bad pump or cooling fan issue?

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment.I have 2004 Honda civic lx 5 speed coupe....175k miles on it I live in Massachusetts.

Comment: This seems to be an overwhelming problem with the D17A1 engines. I can say this because mine (I have an '03 LX) does the same exact thing. The largest problem I see right now with my Civic is it continually eats coolant. As long as I keep it full at the radiator, it won't overheat and it will blow hot air from the heater. It doesn't matter what the amount of coolant you have in the overflow, either. I don't have a fix for it, but I'm going to be putting a new engine in the car because the previous owner let it overheat one too many times.

Answer (score 1):

> Hey car overheating and have no heat

I take that to mean that your temp gauge rises very high (perhaps a warning light) and that you are unable to get warm in the passenger compartment in the winter.

If I understand that correctly, I believe that you've got a huge air bubble inside the cooling system, and the coolant level is way low.

I'm pretty sure your system uses an overflow bottle to ensure that the cooling system is ALWAYS topped up.  My guess is you've got a bad radiator cap, or perhaps a cracked overflow hose. You may well have a coolant leak as well.

Its important to top of the coolant system when the engine is cold. Use a 50/50% mix of distilled water and antifreeze. Don't use plain tap water, that will cause sludge in your radiator over time.

When you do the initial top off you will also want to open a coolant bleeder valve.  It should be somewhere near the top of the engine.  This enables you to fill the coolant system and get out most of the air inside.

Check both springs on the radiator cap.  My guess is on your cap, that small disk hangs loose.

[image: Radiator Cap]

The way this should work is you have a nearly topped off radiator (when engine is totally cold) and an overflow bottle filled to mark on the side of the bottle. What should happen is that when you drive the car, the engine warms up and the coolant expands a bit.  After you park the car at night, the engine cools down.  As it cools it shrinks a bit.  When it does this it creates a vacuum in the cooling system and should suck coolant from the overflow bottle back into the engine.

After a proper initial fill and two or three drive cycles there should be absolutely no air trapped inside your cooling system.

Now if I've misunderstood your comment about `have no heat` that changes the conversation.

A couple of tips.

- I recommend you purchase a Haynes or Chilton type repair manual for your car.  $30 well spent.  That book should also detail the coolant fill / bleed operation in detail.
- If they have one near you, AutoZone has this amazing tool loaner program.  You leave a 100% refundable deposit on special tools.  One of the tools they have is a really nice coolant tester.  You place it on the radiator fill (engine off!), pump the thing to 13 psi and look for coolant leaks. Very easy and safe to use.